ggplot2 grouped stacked bar charts
My data looks like this, each row is a different item:
Year <- c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021)
Group <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)
Type <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

df <- data.frame(Year, Group, Type)

I would like to have a stacked chart on percentages of Type grouped by Group and then faceted by Year.


Step 1: Create a new variable to calculate the percentages of Type grouped by Year and Group.
Step 2: Convert the Group and Type variables into factors.
Step 3: Create the plot using the geom_bar() function.

Complete code:
# Data remains the same
Year <- c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021)
Group <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)
Type <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

# Step 1: Create a new percent variable counting the types

df <- data.frame(Year, Group, Type) %>% 
  group_by(Year, Group) %>% 
  count(Type) %>% 
  mutate(perc_type = n / sum(n)) # Percent

# Step 2: Convert variables into factors

df$Group <- as.factor(df$Group)
df$Type <- as.factor(df$Type)

# Step 3: Create the plot

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = perc_type, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + # This function allows the variable to be visualized as a percent
  facet_wrap(vars(Year))



Hope it helps.

Well written answer +1
